# visual studio 2010 setup project - shortcut to web page

Tags: setup-project

Is there anyway to create a web link without using custom action?

I want to add a web link to start menu that will open default browser on target machine and browse the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use [IniFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) table like in [this post](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1026.htm).

Visual Studio setup projects do not support this, so you will need to edit your MSI with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). A simpler approach is to use [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or a [different setup authoring tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) which offers more control over your MSI package.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was adding the .url file to SetupProject and it did the trick (as it described in the post @Cosmin Pirvu referenced to).